# Twitter OAuth - Unusual 401 Loop Error

Tags: node.js, twitter, oauth, amazon-ec2, twitter-oauth

I'm using the twitter API (v1.1) for an app I'm working on. I'm running a node.js server on EC2 with **node-oauth** to interface with the API.

At one point in my code I run a loop to quickly to obtain the five latest tweets from a list of users

Pseudo code:

```
for (user in users){
   oauth.get(https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json?count=5&user_id=123456)
}
```

The number of users could be anywhere from 1-30. The code works fine when there are less than twelve users, but starts randomly throwing 401 errors when there are more roughly than twelve users. Sometimes it happens on the 13th API call, sometimes on the 14th or 18th - basically it's not constant.

```
 { statusCode: 401, data:'{"request":"\\/1.1\\/statuses\\/user_timeline.json","error":"Not authorized."}' }
```

I know I'm not maxing out my rate limit, and I'm confident all the oauth credential are correct so what's going on? I've heard it could have to do with server timing mismatch but I ran ntpstat on my EC2 instance it and seemed fine:

```
 synchronised to NTP server (129.6.15.29) at stratum 2 
     time correct to within 86 ms
     polling server every 1024 s
```

Any clue as to what's going on here?

Thanks

Comment: Follow this: https://twittercommunity.com/t/error-401-unauthorized/367/40